# Maven tar target output folder

Tags: java, maven, build

I currently have a maven project structured as such:

```
-parent module/   
  -child_module1/
     -scripts_directory/
     -src/
        -main/
           -java/
           -resources/
     -test/

  -child_module2/
     -scripts_directory/
     -src/
        -main/
           -java/
           -resources/
     -test/  

  -child_module3/     
    ... (same structure as above child modules)
```

When the project is built it creates a jar for each child module and transfers it to a common directory outside of the execution path; copies all the `dependencies` of each child module into this same directory as well; copies the contents of each child module's `scripts_directory` into another common directory; and finally all its `resources` into another common directory

So the final structure after running mvn install is:

```
/packages/mymavenapp/
  -conf/ (contains all the resources of each child module's resources)
  -lib/ (contains all the child module jars (compiled) and their dependencies)
    -child_module1.jar
    -child_module2.jar
    -child_module3.jar
    -spring jars 
    -more dependency jars
  -scripts/ (contains all the contents of each child's scripts_directory)
    -run_child1_jar.pl
    -run_child2_jar.pl
    -run_child3_jar.pl
```

I currently have this build structure working. I would like to `tar` the directory `/packages/mymavenapp` into `mymavenapp.tar.gz` and push it to its nodes.

I know I can have a shell script that tars this directory but would like to know if I can do this in the maven build cycle easily

EDIT:

The location of the final target directory is not as important so the target directory

```
 mymavenapp/
```

could be inside the parent module's directory so as long as the structure inside `mymavenapp/` stays the same along with its contents ie. `mymavenapp/conf/`; `mymavenapp/lib/`; `mymavenapp/scripts/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [maven-assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) in saperate build profile, at the end of build invoke maven build with that build profile

assembly plugin is very flexible and it takes a configuration file where you can define your input files and the location of that file inside tar file and the location of final tar file for example

Comment: hmm. This requires a completely new 'maven project' which may be overkill

Comment: This doesn't require new maven project